# Lifetime of literal values inside Zig comptime function

Tags: lifetime, literals, compile-time, zig

## Literal's lifetime inside a function

In the following code, is the reference returned by the function a bad pointer ?

```
fn hello() *const u8 {
    return &'A';
}
```

No, because the `'A'` literal has a static lifetime (or is it?). But what about the following function ?

```
fn world(c: u8) []const u8 {
    return &.{ c };
}
```

Still no, because, again, the literal array has a static lifetime, but this leads to strange behavior if called multiple times:

```
const a = world('a');
const b = world('b');
print("{s} {s}\n", .{a, b});
```

```
b b
```

The previous value (`'a'`) has been overwritten has the referenced literal is the same over all call to the function `world()`.

## Comptime function

What happens now if the `world()` function is comptime ?

```
fn world(comptime c: u8) []const u8 {
    return &.{ c };
}
```

Apparently, it creates a distinct static literal for each call:

```
const a = world('a');
const b = world('b');
print("{s} {s}\n", .{a, b});
```

```
a b
```

## Macro to build literal tree

Now, the same problem but applied to a concrete situation.

I have a `Regex` type representing a regular expression :

```
const Regex = union(enum) {
    literal: u8,
    sequence: []const Regex,
    repeat: *const Regex,
    choice: []const Regex,
};
```

But directly writing a literal regex formula can be cumbersome:

```
const regex: Regex = .{ .sequence = &.{ .{ .literal = 'h' }, .{ .choice = &.{ ... } } } };
```

To ease the writing of literal regular expression, some helper functions can come to the rescue :

```
// make the regular expression optional (aka the `?` operator)
fn opt(comptime self: Regex) Regex {
    // choice between itself and an empty sequence
    return .{ .choice = &.{ self, .{ .sequence = &.{} } } };
}
```

We could also image a function which convert a string literal to a regex (sequence of literals).

This seems to work as long as the function is comptime. But I don't want approximate confidence, I want full confidence in its correctness. Please correct me if my understanding of lifetime of literal is wrong.

## Zig's comptime print

It turns out Zig have, in its standard library, such a function. The `std.fmt.comptimePrint`. It creates a local variable and returns a pointer to it.

```
pub inline fn comptimePrint(comptime fmt: []const u8, args: anytype) *const [count(fmt, args):0]u8 {
    comptime {
        var buf: [count(fmt, args):0]u8 = undefined;
        _ = bufPrint(&buf, fmt, args) catch unreachable;
        buf[buf.len] = 0;
        return &buf;
    }
}
```

But what does the `inline` and the `comptime { ... }` do here ? Why are they necessary ? What would happen if they weren't there ? Is the returned buffer's lifetime static ?

Answer (score 2):

[`inline`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#inline-fn) forces the function to be semantically inlined at the callsite. [`comptime {}`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Compile-Time-Expressions) guarantees that the code is evaluated at compile-time. This means that the content of the buffer is known at compile-time and likely lives in the [global constant data section](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Where-are-the-bytes) at runtime. In other words, yes, the lifetime of the buffer is static.